# How to move focus out of ScrollView on Android with a remote control?

Tags: android

An app has the following in a layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContents"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:minWidth="120dip"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:text="@string/set_up">
                    <requestFocus />
                </Button>
               ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewNewDevice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
       //Some EditText and AutoCompleteTextView controls
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can see that the button gets focus intially.  Once the focus is moved into the ScrollView, it can never get out of it with a remote control.  Could anyone offer a tip on how to get the focus out of a ScrollView with a remote control?

Answer (score 0):

I am using android:nextFocusUp = "@id/buttonAboveScrollView" for the top element inside the ScrollView to allow the focus to move out of the ScrollView when a remote control is used.